# Referencing v-model

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to reference a v-model in one of my html files.
I've gone ahead and created a jsbin with a small example of what I'm trying to achieve:

https://jsbin.com/saqirekasa/edit?html,js,output

Essentially, what seems to be happening is that Vue gives an error like this in my actual project:

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid expression. Generated function body:  scope.lookForUser({{scope.input_field}})
```

The problem (I believe) appears to be when I introduced this line:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="email-address" id = "button_email_submit" v-model = "input_field"/>
```

And then tried to reference the v-model 'input field' as such:

```
<button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" type="button" v-on= "click: lookForUser(@{{input_field}})">
```

Any ideas why Vue doesn't like this statement?

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out with a bit more fiddling around -- the issue was I was not supposed to use @{{input_field}} but rather simply pass input_field text into the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!  Here's my example code in case it helps anyone.

```
<div v-repeat="company: companies">
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
          <a href="#" v-on="click: selected_company_id = company.id">                  
      </div>
</div>
```

I kept wanting to wrap the company.id in mustache brackets:

`<a href="#" v-on="click: selected_company_id = {{company.id}}">`

but I'm assuming that since it is already part of an expression, you don't need to do that.